# iAd Banner white continue to showing

Tags: ios, show-hide, iad, adbannerview

Adding a iAd banner in my app, but when the banner is empty (white) the banner not become hidden, i try two type of code one is:

on my `.h`

```
    #import <iAd/iAd.h>

    @interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> {

        ADBannerView *homeBanner;
    }

    //----------------------------------iAd BANNER-------------------------//
    @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bannerIsVisible;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ADBannerView *homeBanner;
    @end
```

on class `.m`

```
@synthesize homeBanner, bannerIsVisible;

//------------iAd Banner---------------------------------------//
- (void)bannerViewDidload:(ADBannerView *)abanner {

    if (!self.bannerIsVisible){

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        homeBanner.frame = CGRectOffset(homeBanner.frame, 0.0, 50.0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    } 
}
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)aBanner {

    if (!self.bannerIsVisible){

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        homeBanner.frame = CGRectOffset(homeBanner.frame, 0.0, -320.0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

with this code if the banner is white, continue showing.

Try to a second code:

on my `.h`

```
    #import <iAd/iAd.h>

    @interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> {

        ADBannerView *homeBanner;
    }

    //----------------------------------iAd BANNER-------------------------//
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ADBannerView *homeBanner;
    @end
```

and on `.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [homeBanner setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidload:(ADBannerView *)banner {

        [homeBanner setHidden:NO];
        NSLog(@"Showing");

}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [homeBanner setHidden:YES];
    NSLog(@"Hidden");
}
```

and finally have the same problem.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the NSLog instructions firing as they should be?

Comment: No I dident see the NSLog nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the delegate for the bannerView?

Try this in you viewDidLoad -

```
[homeBanner setDelegate:self];
```